# which operator would be best to use for solving this query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to solve this question and I'm not sure what operator to use. I was thinking of using nested query.

This is the question: Find the lastname and firstname of members who have borrowed both books titled “XML and XQuery” and “XQuery: The XML Query Language” either currently or in the past.

This is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE Book
    (bookID INT,
    ISBN INT,
    title varchar (30),
    author  varchar (20),
    publish_year INT,
    category varchar(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (bookID));  

CREATE TABLE Member
    (memberID INT,
    lastname varchar (20),
    firstname varchar (20),
    address varchar(20),
    phone_number INT,   
    limit_ INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (memberID));

CREATE TABLE CurrentLoan
    (memberID INT ,
    bookID INT,
    loan_date DATE,
    due_date DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (memberID, bookID),
    FOREIGN KEY (memberID) REFERENCES Member(memberID),
    FOREIGN KEY (bookID) REFERENCES Book(bookID));

CREATE TABLE History
    (memberID INT,
    bookID INT,
    loan_date DATE,
    return_date DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (memberID, bookID, loan_date),
    FOREIGN KEY (memberID) REFERENCES Member(memberID),
    FOREIGN KEY (bookID) REFERENCES Book(bookID));

INSERT INTO Book VALUES (10, 1113312336, 'The Dog', 'Jack Crow', 1990, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (12, 2221254896, 'Worms', 'Jim Kan', 2013, 'childrens');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (13, 3332546987, 'Crow', 'Jan Flo', 2000, 'fiction'); 
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (14, 4443456215, 'Big Dog', 'Lan Big', 1993, 'children');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (15, 5552314569, 'Green Apple', 'Theo Brown', 1978, 'children');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (16, 6664581631, 'Red Bean', 'Khang Nk', 2017, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (17, 7771452369, 'XML and XQuery', 'Author Le', 2017, 'non-fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (18, 8881245525, 'The Dark Room', 'Jack Se', 2017, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (19, 9991123546, 'Lonely Mens', 'Geen Brown', 2014, 'refrence');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (20, 1122112356, 'XQuery: The XML Query Language', 'Heart Le', 2002, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO BOOK VALUES (21, 1212121212, 'The Giving Tree', 'Shel Silverstein', 1964, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO BOOK VALUES (22, 1212121212, 'The Giving Tree', 'Shel Silverstein', 1964, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO BOOK VALUES (23, 1313131313, 'The Lazy Dog', 'Jake Red', 2016, 'children');
INSERT INTO BOOK VALUES (24, 1313131313, 'The Lazy Dog', 'Jake Red', 2016, 'children');
INSERT INTO BOOK VALUES (25, 1414141414, 'The Very Blue Boy', 'Ben Jen', 2006, 'fiction');

INSERT INTO Member VALUES (001, 'Lee', 'Nancy', 'Brownlea Drive', 1254896325, 10);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (002, 'Le', 'Ray', '10th Street', 1234561256, 2);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (003, 'Kan', 'Charlie', '5th Street', 1234567236, 8);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (004, 'Brown', 'Joe', 'Elm Street', 1234567845, 9);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (005, 'Smith', 'John', '33 East', 1234567890, 3);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (006, 'Khang', 'Nkaujyi', '358 Spencer', 2145345625, 5);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (007, 'Jones', 'David', '4th Street', 14812365789, 10);

INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (001, 20, '13-SEP-17', '14-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (002, 19, '13-JAN-17', '15-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (005, 17, '14-FEB-17', '12-MAR-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (003, 15, '12-OCT-17', '09-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (005, 18, '13-APR-17', '12-MAY-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (007, 25, '02-OCT-17', '25-DEC-17');

INSERT INTO History VALUES (001, 17, '14-Jan-17', '04-JUN-17');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (003, 19, '12-Jan-17', '04-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (002, 13, '14-APR-17', '08-OCT-17');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (005, 20, '14-MAY-17', '04-DEC-17');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (007, 12, '02-OCT-16', '25-DEC-16');
COMMIT;
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT Book.title, lastname, firstname
FROM Book, Member
WHERE Book.title like '%XML%XQuery%' or title like '%XQuery%XML%'
AND EXISTS (SELECT Book.bookID, Member.memberID
    FROM Member, Book, CurrentLoan
    WHERE Book.bookID = CurrentLoan.bookID
    AND Member.memberID = CurrentLoan.memberID);
```

Comment: You could at least start your query with selecting the first and last names.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thats what i try but the result is still the same

Comment: I guess CurrentLoan table represent currently books borrowed and History table represents past borrows.

Comment: @HatimStovewala correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this query works for you.

```
select m.firstname, m.lastname
from (select memberID, bookID from CurrentLoan union all select memberID, bookID from History) a
join Member m on m.memberID = a.memberID
join Book b on b.bookID = a.bookID
where b.title IN ('XML and XQuery', 'XQuery: The XML Query Language');
```

Comment: yes that work, but could you explain the process of it?

Comment: I believe that the query returns a user if he borrows just one of the books as well.

Comment: what is consider a?

Comment: @tubvajlis The above query returns four people, however, I believe that the correct solution should return nobody (for these book names) since none of those people borrowed both books (now or in history)!

Comment: is there a simpler way of writing this query? I'm new to DBMS and my professor haven't taught us how to write query in that way.

Comment: @tubvajlis "my professor haven't taught us how to write a query in that way" so maybe it is a time to learn something by yourself!

Comment: @RadimBača that is true, but I've been googling and still trying to figure it out with no results.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform `UNION` of `History` and `CurrentLoan` and then use `INTERSECT`

```
  SELECT m.lastname, m.firstname
  FROM
  (
      SELECT distinct memberID ,bookID FROM CurrentLoan 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT distinct memberID ,bookID FROM History
  ) t 
  JOIN BOOK b ON t.bookid = b.bookid AND b.TITLE = 'Crow'
  JOIN Member m ON m.memberID = t.memberID
INTERSECT
  SELECT m.lastname, m.firstname
  FROM
  (
      SELECT distinct memberID ,bookID FROM CurrentLoan 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT distinct memberID ,bookID FROM History
  ) t 
  JOIN BOOK b ON t.bookid = b.bookid AND b.TITLE = 'Lonely Mens'
  JOIN Member m ON m.memberID = t.memberID
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to find those users who have bought exactly two different books with the expected names.

```
SELECT m.lastname, m.firstname
FROM
(
    SELECT distinct memberID ,bookID FROM CurrentLoan 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT distinct memberID ,bookID FROM History
) t 
JOIN BOOK b ON t.bookid = b.bookid AND b.TITLE IN ('Lonely Mens', 'Crow')
JOIN Member m ON m.memberID = t.memberID
GROUP BY t.memberID, m.lastname, m.firstname
HAVING count(distinct t.bookid) = 2
```